# Position object centrally inside a c# form

Tags: c#, position

I have no idea why this is difficult to find out how to do. It baffles me.

Say I have a button inside the form. I want on form load for the buttons position from top to be `form height`/2 - `button height`/2 and position from left to be `form width`/2 - `button width`/2.

Or any other way of making it central...

Comment: Do you want to place button in center?

Comment: what is a c# form supposed to be? A web form or a windows form?

Comment: It seems you found your solution because you answered your own question. Can you mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how to do it if the object is named `groupBox1`:

```
int X = (this.Width / 2) - (groupBox1.Width / 2);
int Y = (this.Height / 2) - (groupBox1.Height / 2);
groupBox1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button is named `button1` and your Form `form1`:

```
button1.Location.X = (form1.Width / 2) - (button1.Width / 2);
button1.Location.Y = (form1.Height / 2) - (button1.Height/ 2);
```

Disclaimer: untested

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken what you are looking is Docking.

I think that your question is answer here
[How to dock a windows form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214351/how-to-dock-a-windows-form-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In design time, go to menu `Format` > `Center in form` and center your button. Then remove all the anchors for this button. This will keep in the center.

Answer (score 0):

> Other way of making it central

Add `TableLayoutPanel` to a form, make its `Dock = Fill`. Add 3 rows and 3 columns. Drop your button into a middle cell. Make middle cell type `AutoSize` (row and column). Make others columns and rows type `Percent` and enter `50` there.

Whenever you resize the form, `TableLayoutPanel` will layout your button in the middle.